# dynamically change close icon of search view - android

Tags: android

i have implemented a listview with a search view. so, while user is typing in the search view it will search the matching entries in list and correspondingly updates the list view to display matching entries.

but i want to ask is,
is there any way through which i can determine, that the text entered into searchview is not present in the list. so that for that entry i can display the add button to add that entry in list 
now my code is,

```
addLabelText =(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.addLabelText);
        addLabelText.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,lv_arr);//here lv_arr is String[]
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return false;
}
```

in short, i want to change close icon of searchview dynamically, 
if the adapter returns some entries it should display close icon... if it is empty then it should display + icon, so that user can add new entry to the list...

i know, we can chnange close icon of seach view by using,

```
int closeButtonId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
ImageView closeButtonImage = (ImageView) addLabelText.findViewById(closeButtonId);
closeButtonImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.close);
```

but how to write condition to determine if the adapter display empty list. or not

Comment: You don't have to do it dynamically. You can do it by a separate style.

Comment: will you please elaborate.??

Comment: See my answer here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40124611/android-actionbar-searchview-change-icon-and-remove-extra-spacing/40124722?noredirect=1#comment67519662_40124722

Comment: but , i have a condition, ==>> is filtered list contains any child? -->if yes, then close icon should be "X".....if no, then close icon should be "+"

Comment: See this.
https://gist.github.com/dbachelder/9587898
and this
nlopez.io/how-to-style-the-actionbar-searchview-programmatically/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what i wanted, but listview.setEmptyView(R.id....) helped me.